# Panel using stored procedure - Code not reacting as expected

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures, panel

I have hit a small issue and hoping someone might be able to assist. I am using a panel - On the page load, it should list all the products as no category has been selected as per stored procedure (this works perfectly).

When a user clicks on a specific category, it should only show the products that have the specific `CategoryID`. When I run the code in SQL, it works a dream for this part too, so assume the stored procedure is ok.

At

```
CategoryID = CategoryID
```

in `GetProducts`,  I get

> Warning: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?

However I am following a tutorial video and this works fine. Is there another silly error that is preventing it from working?

I think I have included all the required code - sorry if its a bit overkill!!

Thanks as ever in advance - Jack
Code behind `pnlCategories`:

```
private void GetProducts(int CategoryID)
{
        ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart();
        {
            CategoryID = CategoryID;
        };
```

Comment: Hey Jack, that looks like a c# error and not a SQL Server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error identified - additional ";" added at following line:

```
    ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart();
```

Code now reads

```
     ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart()
        {
            CategoryID = CategoryID
        };
```

and functions as expected!

Answer (score 0):

that looks like a c# error and not a SQL Server error.
The problem is here in your GetProducts method.  `CategoryID = CategoryID;`

C# is case sensitive. If you check your tutorial carefully, one of these will probably be lower case. Make sure you type that carefully. 
try code change below and see where the compiler complains.
CategoryID = categoryID;

```
 private void GetProducts(int CategoryID)
    {
        ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart();
        {
            CategoryID = CategoryID;
        };

        dlProducts.DataSource = null;
        dlProducts.DataSource = k.GetProdcuts();
        dlProducts.DataBind();
    }
```